# Brownian motion as scaling limit of random walks

Tags: statistics, brownian-motion, random-walk, self-learning

Consider a geometric scaled walk,

\begin{align*}
X_k &= X_0\exp[\frac{1}{\sqrt{k}}(S_k)]\\
&= X_0\exp[\frac{1}{\sqrt{k}}(2T_k - k)]
\end{align*}

where $T_k \space \tilde{} \space Binomial(k, 0.5)$

How can I use the Central Limit Theorem to show that the cdf of $\frac{S_k}{\sqrt{k}}$ converges to that of the standard normal as $k \rightarrow \infty$? Is this is the same as showing that a random walk converges to the Brownian motion in continuous time?

I can't seem to find a formal proof of this result anywhere so any guidance would be much appreciated.

Comment: The commonest approach is to show that the characteristic functions converge to the characteristic function of a standard normal.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Proving the normal approximation to the binomial](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1894554/proving-the-normal-approximation-to-the-binomial)